# $\mathfrak{sl}_2$-action on Young diagrams

Tags: reference-request, co.combinatorics, young-tableaux

Let $\mathcal{Y}$ be a vector $\mathbb{Q}$-space of all Young diagrams.  Denote by  $\delta_\lambda$ the Young diagram of the partition $\lambda$  and $c(\square)$ be
the content of the square $\square$:
$$
c(\square) = {\rm column}(\square) -  {\rm row}(\square)\,
$$
where ${\rm column}(\square)$ denotes the column number of the square $\square$.

The paper

> A. Okounkov, SL(2) and z-measures, Random matrix models and their
> applications (PM Bleher and AR Its, eds). Mathematical Sciences
> Research Institute Publications 40 (2001), pp.407–420

says (without proof) that  the following Kerov's operators ( $z, z'$ are parametrs)

\begin{alignat*}{2}
U\, \delta_\lambda &= \sum_{\mu=\lambda+\square} &(z+c(\square)) \, &\delta_\mu \,\\
L\, \delta_\lambda &= &(zz'+2|\lambda|)\, &\delta_\lambda\,\\
D\, \delta_\lambda &= \sum_{\mu=\lambda-\square} &(z'+c(\square)) \, &\delta_\mu \,,
\end{alignat*}

define a $\mathfrak{sl}_2$ action on $\mathcal{Y}$, i.e.:
$$
\begin{equation}\label{comm}
[D,U]=L\,, \quad [L,U]=2U\,, \quad [L,D]=-2D\,.
\end{equation}
$$

Is there any proof of the statement or it is a trivial  fact?

Comment: I think it shouldn't be too hard to prove directly. It is just a slight extension of Stanley's differential poset identity.